# vue router-link not show params on refresh page

Tags: laravel, vue.js

when i refresh page, the component "music" see 'params' object empty,
can someone help me ?

below the code:

```
route.js:
{
    path: "/music",
    name: "music",
    component: music
}

file that call router-link:
<router-link :to="{name:'music', params:{ title:'Musicc'}} ">Music</router-link>

music component:
<template>
  <div>
    <div>{{title}}</div>
  </div>
</template>
<script>
    export default {
    name: "music",
    computed:{
        title: function(){
            return this.$route.params.title;
        }
      }
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to give the param name in path of you route....perhaps it can be the answer

```
route.js:
{
    path: "/music/:title",
    name: "music",
    component: music
}
```

Comment: dont think so, if i have to pass 20 params, dont want to pass all by path

Comment: but without parameter how did you pass a parameter

Comment: it is the syntax i always used

Comment: lets think about the laravel....if you didnot give a parameter id in your route then how it calls a route that requires a parameter

Answer (score 0):

add `props:true` in route.js

route.js:

```
{
    path: "/music",
    name: "music",
    component: music,
    props: true
}
```

Comment: did it, but params is still empty when refresh page

Comment: param data is lost when refresh the page, it will be just available by the routing navigation inside the app.

Comment: to make it when refresh the page, you need to save the value in the url someething like `/music/:title`

Answer (score 0):

A page refresh is different than clicking on a router link.  Parameters passed by clicking on a router-link do not persist in the page after a page refresh (as William Wang mentioned).  If you need to persist data in spite of a page refresh, think about using Vuex state management instead of passing lots of parameters around.

Answer (score 0):

**Here is your problem**

in the file that call the router-link

```
<router-link :to="{name:'music', params:{ title:'Musicc'}} ">Music</router-link>
```

while in

```
path: "/music"
```

it should be

```
path:"/music/:title"
```

so it a typo